# Is there a way do edit alert that pops up before making a call?

Tags: iphone, call, alert

In my application I implemented calling a number programmatically using following code:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:@"180"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

When I press the button which triggers this method, the alert appears on screen. The alert wants you to confirm the call so you are aware of the number you are calling.

In the alert label there is written just number. But I want to edit it so it will show something more human like "Do you want to call 180?"